# XC9 entity composer templates: circular template inheritance

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am assigning an Entity Composer template by Item Defintion to a Sellable Item. This shows fine in the Business Tools, but the generated Sitecore item templates have a circular dependency.

The generated template under "/sitecore/templates/Commerce/Catalog Generated/", "Drinks" in my example, contains a reference to the generated component: "/sitecore/templates/Commerce/Catalog Generated/Components/Drinks". The component has a link back to the item under "Catalog Generated", this causes a circular dependency error:

```
3688 14:55:33 ERROR Circular template inheritance detected in 'Drinks'
3688 14:55:33 ERROR This may be caused by explicitly assigned base id's or by the setting 'DefaultBaseTemplate' in web.config.
3688 14:55:33 ERROR Template trail: Commerce/Catalog Generated/Components/Drinks : Commerce/Catalog Generated/Components/Drinks : Commerce/Catalog Generated/Components/Drinks : ...
```

Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Is your method return Json data?

Comment: I too have same issue while using entity composer and do update data tempates from content editor- its creating circular reference of templates. How to avoid such issues?

Comment: @Jyoti no solution yet, still working with Sitecore Support on solving it.

Comment: Sitecore Support acknowledged this as bug, no solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is registered by Sitecore as bug #276414.

The workaround is to have different `Name` values for the `ComposerTemplate` and the `EntityView` that it contains.